# Unabling jButton until all text fileds are filled

Tags: java, jbutton

This is my Frame: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpogs.jpg)
How to disable the **"Add"** jButton until all text fileds are filled?

Answer (score 1):

You do is like this:

Add `DocumentListener` to every `JTextField`, and then in the inside the button enable method which is a custom method, you can check if all the required fields are filled

```
jtextfield.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        setButtonEnable();
    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        setButtonEnable();
    }
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        setButtonEnable();
    }
    private void setButtonEnable() {
        // check all the text fields here
        boolean filled = tf1.getText().lenght > 0 && tf2.getText....;
        button.setEnable(filled);
    }
});
```